# С# в C++ (IsProcessorFeaturePresent)

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, функции

Помогите пожалуйста переделать маленький кусочек кода с **C#** в **C++**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (ProcessorFeature feature in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProcessorFeature)))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(feature.ToString() + "\t: " + IsProcessorFeaturePresent(feature));
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32")]
    static extern bool IsProcessorFeaturePresent(ProcessorFeature processorFeature);

    enum ProcessorFeature : uint
    {
        PF_FLOATING_POINT_PRECISION_ERRATA = 0,
        PF_FLOATING_POINT_EMULATED = 1,
        PF_COMPARE_EXCHANGE_DOUBLE = 2,
        PF_MMX_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE = 3,
        PF_PPC_MOVEMEM_64BIT_OK = 4,
        PF_ALPHA_BYTE_INSTRUCTIONS = 5,
        PF_XMMI_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE = 6,
        PF_3DNOW_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE = 7,
        PF_RDTSC_INSTRUCTION_AVAILABLE = 8,
        PF_PAE_ENABLED = 9,
        PF_XMMI64_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE = 10,
        PF_SSE_DAZ_MODE_AVAILABLE = 11,
        PF_NX_ENABLED = 12,
        PF_SSE3_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE = 13,
        PF_COMPARE_EXCHANGE128 = 14,
        PF_COMPARE64_EXCHANGE128 = 15,
        PF_CHANNELS_ENABLED = 16,
        PF_XSAVE_ENABLED = 17,
        PF_SECOND_LEVEL_ADDRESS_TRANSLATION = 20,
        PF_VIRT_FIRMWARE_ENABLED = 21,
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь создать перечисление enum но пишет нужен идентификатор. Подключал lib но не помогает.

```
#pragma comment (lib, "Kernel32.lib")
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Сделайте просто массив значений. [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724482(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так ведь мне нужно что бы он выводил try or false, а msdn я уже читал.

Comment: Так проблема только в выводе true/false? :-\

Comment: @VladD проблема в правельной реализации и уменьшении строк кода, на ум приходит обычный `if`, но его тогда будет очень много, на каждую инструкцию, хотелось сделать также компактно